# matrix with two unknowns

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I am to calculate the value of this matrix

$$
         \begin{bmatrix}
         1 & 1 & 1 \\
         1 & 1 & a \\
         1 & b & 1 
         \end{bmatrix}
 $$

I do a basic transformation to

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}        
          1 & 1 & 1 \\
         0 & -b+1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -a+1
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

We have the "stairs" in the left corner. How could we proceed to get the right answer? I know how to calculate basic matrix , but variables $a,b$ in it makes it hard for me to understand it

Comment: Is your question about the rank of the initial matrix ? If so, say it explicitly.

Comment: What do **you** mean  by the "value of a matrix"?  Did you mean to say the "determinant"?  If so, then the determinant of a triangular matrix, as you have in the "transformed" matrix is just the product of the numbers on the main diagonal.  However, the "transformation" you use to reduce to the triangular matrix (row reduction?) may change the determminant of at matrix.  And, in fact, the determinant of that triangular matrix is NOT the same as the determinant of the original matrix.  I have talked about the determinant but I still don't know if that is what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do, now that you have a triangularized matrix, is to "discuss" according to the values of $a$ and $b$:

- if $a\neq1$ and $b\neq1$, the determinant is $\neq 0$: thus rank=3.
- if $a=1$ and $b\neq1$, the determinant is zero, thus rank $<3$ but the two first vectors are independant, thus rank=2.
- if $a\neq1$ and $b=1$, same conclusion, this time with column 1 and 3.
- if $a=1$ and $b=1$, the rank drops to 1 because all the columns are multiple of the first one.